# PyCharm keyboard shortcut to create new python module

Tags: python, refactoring, keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

In [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) in a Python file I have an import directive for a non-existent module

```
import module_that_does_not_exist
```

Is there a keyboard shortcut I can press to create module_that_does_not_exist.py file in the same directory?